# how to query two different oracle database servers?

Tags: oracle

How do I query two different Oracle database servers using a shell script?
How do I handle connecting to two different servers?
I have two different user ID and password.
I know this is not safe to include the id/pw in the shell script file but can you tell me how this is done?

server 1:

```
s1.mycompnay.com:1587/hr_dev.mycompany.com/HR_DB
```

server 1:

```
s2.mycompnay.com:1587/bank_dev.mycompany.com/BANK_DB
```

my shell script has something this:

> sqlplus  hr_db/$1 << EOF

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that the path between the two servers is open and both servers have a registry in your [tnsnames.ora](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Tnsnames.ora) file:
Using your description you would want two entries

```
HR_DB =
 (DESCRIPTION =
   (ADDRESS_LIST =
     (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(Host = s1.mycompnay.com)(Port = 1587))
   )
 (CONNECT_DATA =
   (SERVICE_NAME = HR_DB)
 )
)

BANK_DB=
     (DESCRIPTION =
       (ADDRESS_LIST =
         (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(Host = s2.mycompnay.com)(Port = 1587))
       )
     (CONNECT_DATA =
       (SERVICE_NAME = BANK_DB)
     )
    )
```

You already noted that it is bad practice to include the passwords in the script so I don't need to comment on that any further. After you get the entries in and have taken steps to ensure that firewalls are open you can test it by [tnsping](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Tnsping)'ing the DBs:

```
tnsping HR_DB
tnsping BANK_DB
```

If those succeed it will tell you such as well as time in MS to return the packets. A failure will be immediately apparent.